# Why the 'declaration of a single variable' in the 'condition' part of the 'for loop' syntax from cpp reference doesn't end up with a semicolon?

Tags: c++

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

> a declaration of a single variable with a brace-or-equals initializer. the initializer is evaluated before each iteration, and if the value of the declared variable converts to false, the loop is exited.

I do noticed that only the concept of `simple declaration` is clearly demonstrated in the reference as one kind of block declaration and by the end of which a semicolon is neccessary. Here the description `declaration of a single variable` is somehow vague. Is it some kind of declaration that omits the semicolon?

The code below is surely incorrect, I just wanna show what if the `condition` syntax is replaced by a normal declaration.

```
for(int i = 0; int k{1};; i) ;
```

Comment: You are literally reading the informal line and asking why your attempt to understand it results in an additional semicolon?  cppreference is not the c++ standard.  The grammar will be more specific.

Comment: an `init-statement` itself includes the semicolon

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks, I will try to find it.

Comment: @sp2danny That is about the first semicolon. Yakk has got the point. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You simply must have two semicolons in a for loop, no more, no less. It's only a matter of formal definition. The "missing" semicolon is always present at the end of the *init-statement*, as the note reminds you. As for looking up the official grammar of C++, good luck with that. For one thing the official standard costs about $200 so you'll have to be content with some not too outdated draft, and frankly if you find cppreference hard to read, you're in for a world of pain looking at the genuine stuff. It's a job for scholars, gurus and compiler manufacturers, not mere mortals.

Comment: The way to indicate that a Stack Overflow question has been solved is **not** to edit the question, but to accept an answer. [You may answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). When the answer came from someone else, it might be appropriate to flag the answer as "community wiki".

Comment: @kuroineko I came across this problem when reading cpp primer and I thought it misses a semicolon after `init-statement`. By reading cppreference, I managed to make out the first semicolon, as the two forms of init-statement both contain an ending semicolon. But the second one really disturbed me, now I get to know that it is a problem of unclear definition.  Thanks for your advice.  And I will find some materials on the difference between the draft and published version.

Comment: The only issue here is cppreference being inaccurate in its statement of the grammar

Comment: This is just an attempt at presenting something less convoluted than the formal C++ grammar by offering an inaccurate but more immediately readable alternative that makes the two semicolons stand out. The two variants are clearly labelled *formal syntax* and *informal syntax* with a comprehensive rationale for the informal variant. What is the problem there? Is there a case where this difference actually matters for more than 0,1% of the people who write C++ code or die trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encounter this question when reading Cpp primer, it states:

```
The syntactic form of the *for statement* is: 
    for (*init-statement condition;expression*)
         statement
```

And I mistakenly thought it missed a semicolon after init-statement. By reading other materials I make out it but came the question above.

In the draft n4892, `condition`s are:

- expression
- attribute-specifier-seq(opt) decl-specifier-seq declarator brace-or-equal-initializer

So it doesn't include an ending semicolon, and the semicolons always follow them are part of the syntax of for-loop.

While the init-statement is of two forms, both of which must end up with semicolon

- expression statement, which always ends up with a semicolon.  Particularly, the  *expression* in it is optional, under which circumstance the  for loop looks like for(; *condition*; *iteration_expression*).
- a simple declaration, which always ends with a semicolon.

So informally, we can think of its syntax as if it contains three parts seperated by two semicolons.